arduino-language-server is not attached to buffer with nvim-lspconfig
I'm trying to use arduino-language-server in order in my neovim configuration.
I'm using NVIM v0.11.0-dev-164+g3a1515bfe (latest nightly version), and use nvim-lspconfig, and mason to set up my lsp.
The lsp seems to work, but it is never attached to a buffer.
In the doc, it is said that you have to have arduino-cli installed (which I have), from the log, it also says it needs to be configured with a file at ~/.arduino15/arduino-cli.yaml (which I have).
And in order for the LSP to work on a project, the project root must have a sketch.yaml file (which I have too).
Any idea why the lsp isn't attaching to the buffer? did I miss something?
Files

sketch.yaml file
default_fqbn: arduino:avr:uno
default_port: /dev/cu.usbmodem1101

:LspInfo (see arduino_language_server not attached to buffer)


Could you tell us what is the current working directory (:pwd)? What is the result after changing the working directory to the folder containing the sketch.yaml (:cd %:h)?

Yep, current wd: /private/tmp/test, changing the wd does not change anything

Did you find a solution for this? Having the same issue.

@MattTew Nop, I will post here if I find anything
